# I will inquire Calender, TimePickerDialog on Android

Tags: java, android, calendar, datepickerdialog

I'll take only two questions related to Android.

I would like to have answered, I'd greatly appreciate it.

## 1

When you convert to java Calender, why values ​​differ?

ex)
year: 1967
month: 12
day: 31

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance ();
calendar.set (Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set (Calendar.MONTH, (month - 1));
calendar.set (Calendar.DATE, day);
calendar.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set (Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set (Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set (Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

(Ver. 2.3x)

input: 1967-12-31 00:00 -> result: 1967-12-30 23:30 (X)

input: 1968-10-01 00:00 -> result: 1968-09-30 23:30 (X)

input: 1968-10-02 00:00 -> result: 1968-10-02 00:00 (O)

In version 4.1.2, all values ​​match, there is no problem like that.

(Ver. 4.1.2)

input: 1967-12-31 00:00 -> result: 1967-12-31 00:00 (O)

input: 1968-10-01 00:00 -> result: 1968-10-01 00:00 (O)

input: 1968-10-02 00:00 -> result: 1968-10-02 00:00 (O)

## 2

When you select (hours or minutes) from the TimePicker**Dialog**, I do not want that the pop-up(keyboard input) is opened.

What should I do now?

I think that I would like you to answer to two questions.

Have a nice day.
Thank you.

Comment: What the 'ver. 4.1...' mean?

Comment: hmm with date picker, please try click enter when you pick your date. or confirm button.

Comment: Gingerbread (2.3–2.3.7), Jelly Bean (4.1–4.3) Android Ver.

Comment: http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/826/how-to-use-datepickerdialog-timepickerdialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer1: Values don't differ in my case, I am using [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html)
here is my code:

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        Log.v(TAG,  "Year: " + year + " ,Month: "+ month + " ,Day: " + day );


    }
}
```

and this is the result:
Year: 2014 ,Month: 1 ,Day: 25

the values are same for three versions of Android, ( 4.1.1, 4.4.2, 2.3.3 ) which I tested.

Comment: First of all, I have the answer, thank you very much.

Value of the data result of or after October 2, 1968 is the same for me.
 
I think the problem is the value of the result of data Prior to October 1, 1968 and are different.


I want,

Disable keyboard input on Android TimePickerDialog.


Thank you, Have a nice day.

Comment: please see this for hiding keyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard